# iPhone, How to show alter dialog on Lock Screen?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I see some apps like 'Lock Calendar' that include this feature, and I know that we can maybe use keyWindows to trace the view and replace the wallpaper etc., but I feel that if the app makes use of this it will probably be refused by Apple ...

or maybe the sdk has provide other API for this purpose?

any tip will be appreciate ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lock Calender" is for jailbroken phones and it would definitely not be approved by Apple. There's no sanctioned way to do what it sounds like you'd want to do.

Comment: but I find the app 'Lock Calender' in the AppStore ....... is not the same app ? I see it show customize calender on the Lock Screen in the screen snapshot descriptions .

Comment: oh... sorry , I can find it on AppSotre now ... but it was show on AppStore yesterday! 

 that all right , thanks for your answers and time ...  I think that the relate API should be publish to developer, since the lock screen also need customize .....

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this will only work on a jail-broken phone. If you want to submit an app with this functionality to the app store, you're out of luck.