# Custom Launcher icon

Tags: iphone, objective-c, lockscreen

i'm just trying to customize the lock screen with custom launcher icon instead of below camera from the lock screen -

[image: Lock Screen]

I was googling about this. I got a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2388111/940096) that we can customize it. But, **Apple won't approve** this.

But, my requirement is simply can we place the our app's icon instead of camera from above pic, to launch our app directly from `Lock Screen`

Any idea/help much appreciated?

Comment: That's not Possible, without JailBreaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entirely impossible on a non-jailbroken device. If you’d like an API for that kind of customization, you should file a feature request for it using the [Bug Reporter](http://bugreporter.apple.com) site.